# MATLAB 2015b broken ActiveX/Excel Controls

Tags: excel, matlab, activex

Having an issue involving the creation of ActiveX handles using MATLAB 2015b. Before updating (from 2013a) I used to create a new Excel application handle using the following 'try catch':

```
global Excel
try
   Excel = actxGetRunningServer('Excel.Application') ;
catch
   Excel = actxserver('Excel.Application');
end
```

Since updating to 2015b, the code still runs through without error, but now the Excel handle created, whilst still of type Excel_Application, has no properties. Calling Excel.get returns a struct with no fields.

Apart from the update, there haven't been any other changes made to the code, and the version of MS Office hasn't changed.

Have there been any changes in the way MATLAB handles the ActiveX interface, or is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: I have 2015b + Office 2016 and cannot reproduce your problem. When calling `Excel = actxserver('Excel.Application');` followed by `Excel.get` I get a whole list of things (definitely not _empty_). Perhaps there is an issue with write permissions, or x32/x64 compatibility?